# More succinct alternative to "lsof -p $(pidof postgres| sed -r 's/ /,/g')"

Tags: io-redirection, lsof

[pidof](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof) returns a space separated list of pids. [lsof -p](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) requires a comma serparated one. This can be solved with sed via:

```
lsof -p `pidof postgres| sed -r 's/ /,/g'`
```

However, the extra pipe seems a bit much for a simple operation. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good alternative is psgrep -d ,

```
lsof -p $(pgrep -d , postgres)
```

`-d` Specifies the delimeter.

Comment: You should use `$(…)` instead of `\`…\``, eg: `lsof -p $(pgrep -d, postgres)`

Comment: Because its more readable or for some comparability issue?

Comment: Backtick command substitution `\`..\`` is legacy syntax with several issues.

    It has a series of undefined behaviors related to quoting in POSIX.
    It imposes a custom escaping mode with surprising results.
    It's exceptionally hard to nest.

$(..) command substitution has none of these problems, and is therefore strongly encouraged.

Comment: yes @A.B. . you can write, inside any nested "$(...)" as if you were writing at the top level (is, as if you were at the script's level). very much easier that all the backslashing you have to resort to when using the backticks.